# List not concatenating properly in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, concatenation

My code all work fine apart from the list at the very bottom "**newList = [i + j for i, j in zip(numberString, products)]**". I expected it to add all the elements within the two list without fault, sort of like this: [a9, b7, c5, d3, e1].

Instead i got this: "['[a', '[b', '9c', ',d', ' e']". Both lists are strings, so i'm not sure why they aren't concatenating properly.

```
# create an empty list for your products.
products = []

# Asking for the number of elements to be inputted.
n = int(input("Enter number of products you're buying : "))

# Some UI for the customer.
print("What are these products?")
# iterating until the range that has been chosen.
for i in range(0, n):
    ele = input()

    products.append(ele)  # adding the element


def sort_numbers(number_list):
    # sorts a list of valid numbers in descending numerical order
    swaps = True
    loopcount = len(number_list) - 1
    while loopcount > 0 and swaps:
        swaps = False
        for i in range(loopcount):
            if number_list[i] < number_list[i + 1]:
                number_list[i], number_list[i + 1] = number_list[i + 1], number_list[i]
                swaps = True
        loopcount = loopcount - 1


def input_numbers(number_list):
    # inputs shopping items and costs and stores them in two lists
    user_input = input('Input a number of type Q to quit ')
    while user_input.upper() != 'Q':
        valid_number = False
        while valid_number == False:
            # use an exception handler to cover non-numeric input
            try:
                number_list.append(int(user_input))
                valid_number = True
            except ValueError:
                print('Please enter a valid number')
                user_input = input('Input a number or type Q to quit ')
        user_input = input('input a number or type Q to quit ')


def totalise_numbers(number_list):
    # sums us the list of numbers
    total = 0
    for i in range(len(number_list)):
        total = total + number_list[i]
    print('The total of the numbers is ', total)
    print('The total of the numbers minus the smallest number is ', total - number_list[0])


# initialise the list
numbers = []

# call the function to create the list of numbers
input_numbers(numbers)

# sort the list in ascending order
sort_numbers(numbers)

# Totalise the numbers
totalise_numbers(numbers)

numberString = str([numbers])

# print the list of numbers
newList = [i + j for i, j in zip(numberString, products)]
print(newList)
print(numbers)
```

Comment: `str([numbers])` what result do you expect?

Comment: You are zipping a list of strings with the string representation of a list.  I think you just want `zip(numbers, products)`.

Comment: @OlvinRoght say my input is a, b, c, d, and e for products and 5, 9, 7, 3 and 1 for numbers. I'm expecting it to bring the list's elements together and make it something like a9, b7, c5, d3 and e1.

Comment: @0x5453 that gives me this error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'"

Comment: @Matt, I've meant what return do you expect from code I've mentioned in comment.

Comment: @OlvinRoght sorry. I expect it to change my numbers list of integers to a list of strings so i can concatenate the two of them together.

Comment: @Matt, to change type of **each element of list** you should call `str()` on each element, not on entire list. You can call it in your list comprehention: `newList = [str(i) + j for i, j in zip(numberString, products)]`.

Comment: I've just had a go at that code by replacing my newlist code with yours. I'm afraid it still gives me out a jumbled mess. I also tried targeting the elements within the list using "numberString = [str(numbers[i])]" but that didn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the few bottom lines with this code.

```
numberString = numbers

# print the list of numbers
newList = [str(i) + j for i, j in zip(numberString, products)]
print(newList)
print(numbers)
```